# Can I train a deep convolutional network without GPUs?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am thinking of building a convolutional neural network as a tracking system application.I get the feeling that all the deep network applications require the use of GPUs. Is it necessary to use GPUs in a task like mine? What are the minimum PC requirements I should have in my laptop ?

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the size and depth of your CNN. If your CNN has one convolution layer, and one fully connected layer, and input images are 64x64, you will be able to train your network on your Laptop in a reasonable time. If you use GoogLeNet with hundred of layers, and train on the entire ImageNet set, than even with a video card it will take you a week, so on a CPU it will never finish training.

For most practical applications, however, it is desirable to have a GPU to train a convolution network. Note that on AWS you can get GPU-enabled instances for a rather reasonable price, especially if you get spot instances, so you don't necessarily need to have a GPU locally.

Last note: most of the frameworks (theano, torch, caffe, mxnet, tensorflow) allow you to execute the same model on CPU and on GPU with minor or no modifications to the code, so you can prototype locally on the CPU with a small set of images, and then when your model works, train it on AWS on a GPU instance.

Comment: Yea, Am indeed thinking of trying the Amazon cloud GPUs . At least feel this is  good as a first trial  training a deep neural net .. Opinion much appreciated,thanks.